# STOP INTERNET EXPLORER FROM PRINTING WHITE TEXT GREY

Tags: css, internet-explorer, printing, background-image

When printing, internet explorer 11 changes the text color white to the color grey

```
<style>
.s1{
    FONT-SIZE: 97.8px;
    FONT-FAMILY: Arial-BoldMT_o;
    FONT-WEIGHT: bold;
    color: rgb(255,255,255);
    }
</style>
<div id='t1' class='s1'>Print these letters white - not grey!</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is a known issue. I also tested the issue with Google Chrome and it also prints the text in gray color.

The reason is that the browser thinks that there is no meaning of printing white text on white paper because user cannot see it. The browser can't guess about your purpose to print the white text. That's why the browser prints it in gray color.

I suggest you try to refer steps below.

1. Go to **File** menu.
2. Click on **Page setup** option.
3. Checked the option called **Print background colors and images**.

[image]

4. Click **OK**.

Now, if you print the page you will notice that text is printed in white color. You need to set the background color of the page to see the effect.

Answer (score 0):

try this : 
change the

```
.s1  { your css here } => #t1 { your css here }
```

may helps

or change your html code

```
id='t1' class='s1'
```

to => only :

```
class='s1'
```

all about "CSS Specificity" 
https://dev.to/emmabostian/css-specificity-1kca